# Problem with understanding why 2 solutions of a combinatorics task don't give the same result

Tags: combinatorics

The task is: In how many ways can we pick 6 people from a group of 4 girls and 6 boys so that there are at least 2 girls?

The first solution, which we did in school, is to divide into 3 different cases: the first being 2 girls and 4 boys, the second 3 girls and 3 boys and the third 4 girls and 2 boys. Calculate each of those and add them up.

The second solution that i came up with at home, because it seemed simpler, is to just choose 2 girls and then any 4 of the 8 people remaining, since it doesn't matter if its a boy or a girl.

The solutions don't give the same result but i can't understand why. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first method yields the solution
$$\binom{4}{2}\binom{6}{4} + \binom{4}{3}\binom{6}{3} + \binom{4}{4}\binom{6}{2}$$

You proposed the alternative solution 
$$\binom{4}{2}\binom{8}{4}$$
However, this solution counts the same selections more than once.  If three girls are selected, your proposed solution counts each selection three times, once for each of the $\binom{3}{2}$ ways you can select two of the three girls as the two girls you have selected and the third girl as being among the other eight people from whom you are selecting.  If four girls are selected, your proposed solution counts each selection six times, once of for each of the $\binom{4}{2}$ ways you can select two of the four girls to be the two girls selected and the other two girls as being among the other eight people from whom you are selecting.  Notice that 
$$\binom{2}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{6}{4} + \binom{3}{2}\binom{4}{3}\binom{6}{3} + \binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{4}\binom{6}{2} = \binom{4}{2}\binom{8}{4}$$

Comment: Thank you so much, now it makes complete sense. I hate getting stuck on a simple question like this one... Thank you again, perfect clarification